# Нужно создать переменную в twig сохранив в нее значение из $_GET

Tags: php, twig

```
{% set loginform as app.request.get('login') %}
<p class="input">
    <label for="login">Логин</label>
    <input name="login" id="login" pattern="^[А-Яа-яA-Za-z0-9*-/_]+$" required value="{{ login }}">
    <a href="change.php?login={{ loginform }}">Изменить</a>
</p>
```

Выводит

> 'Unexpected token "name" of value "as"

Как исправить?

Comment: {% set loginform as app.request.get('login') %}
<p class="input">
    <label for="login">Логин</label>
    <input name="login" id="login" pattern="^[А-Яа-яA-Za-z0-9*-/_]+$" required value="{{ login }}">
    <a href="change.php?login={{ loginform }}">Изменить</a>
</p>

Answer (score 2):

```
{% set loginform = app.request.query.get('login') %}
```

Для $_GET переменных:

```
{{ app.request.query.get("page") }}
```

Для $_POST переменных:

```
{{ app.request.parameter.get("login") }}
```

Comment: тогда ошибки нет но http://localhost/twig/change.php?login=

Comment: <p class="input">
    <label for="login">Логин</label>
    <input name="login" id="login" pattern="^[А-Яа-яA-Za-z0-9*-/_]+$" required value="{{ login }}">
    <a href='change.php?login={{ app.request.query.get("login") }}'>Изменить</a>
</p>   Результат  тоже пустой http://localhost/twig/change.php?login=

Comment: <p class="input"> <label for="login">Логин</label> <input name="login" id="login" pattern="^[А-Яа-яA-Za-z0-9*-/_]+$" required value="{{ login }}"> <a href='change.php?login={{ app.request.query.get("login") }}'>Изменить</a> </p> Результат тоже пустой localhost/twig/change.php?login=